# navbar-brand + toggler

Tags: html5, node.js, bootstrap-4, toggle

Estou estudando bootstrap e durante um projeto não consegui atingir o efeito desejado. No caso o grupo de botões que era pra ficar a direita da tela, do outro lado da linha, não vai. Ainda não inseri CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Job Finder</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Job Finder</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggler navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Ver vagas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link btn btn-primary" href="add.html">Abrir vagas</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma das formas de chegar no resultado esperado sem utilizar css próprio, apenas classes do bootstrap, seria inserir dois elementos `span`. No primeiro vc coloca uma classe **m-auto** para que o restante do conteúdo após ele se alinhe para a direita. No segundo vc coloca a `ul` com os links, se clicar em ver **`Página toda`** verá que os link estão alinhados à direita:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Job Finder</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Job Finder</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="#navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <span class="m-auto"></span>
          <span>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Ver vagas</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link btn btn-primary" href="add.html">Abrir vagas</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

**OBS:** Acho que não precisara ter `ul > li > a` para os links, simples botões resolveriam.

**OBS:** Ou vc utiliza a versão pacote (bundle) que é um arquivo **js** único, ou, vc utiliza o separado (separate) com o `popper` e na sequência o js do bootstrap, como pode ser visto na [documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#js).

Comment: Resolveu, muito obrigado, eu estudei a anos atrás programação de web e estou voltando agora, como as coisas mudaram de lá pra cá...